# Language setting ignored after programatically calling call_command('dumpdata')

Tags: django, django-views

I'm currently programmatically calling dumpdata to export the data from my django app.

```
from django.core.management import call_command
# and various other imports not directly relevant

response = HttpResponse(mimetype='application/json', )
response['Content-Disposition'] = "filename=%s" % backup_name
sys.stdout = response
call_command('dumpdata')
```

The export works well (if a tad slow) but afterwards settings.LANGUAGE_CODE is ignored and all pages revert to back to the original language English. Any ideas why this is happening?

I'm using the following:
- Python 2.7
- Django 1.3
- Rosetta for managing language translations

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is likely caused by code in the `django.core.management.base.BaseCommand` object.  The explanation in the code is:

```
# Switch to English, because django-admin.py creates database content
# like permissions, and those shouldn't contain any translations.
# But only do this if we can assume we have a working settings file,
# because django.utils.translation requires settings.
```

The code which does the actual language switch is:

```
from django.utils import translation
translation.activate('en-us')
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped resolve the issue.
I've followed my code above with: `translation.activate(settings.LANGUAGE_CODE)`

Comment: Does that yield the correct language if the user has changed it in their session?